# Regular Expression for tackling special symbols

Tags: python, regex

I have an example here :

```
>>> txt1
'fdf\\.\\..dgg'
```

I intend to find a regex that will return me the special symbols .

So i tried this .

```
>>> ans=re.search("\w+[\|.]*\w+",txt1)
>>> ans.group()
'fdf'
```

The \w+ will find words continuing.
The [\|.] was supposed to find \ or . (dot) . The star was supposed to continue for next entry.
Again, the \w+ was supposed to find trailing words.

Please guide what is wrong here?
Or the concept is not exactly what i think it is ...
Thanks in advance to all....
As you can see , the idea is not working .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the alternation operator `|` in a character class. Inside `[  ]` a pipe stands for exactly that character. Your backslash escapes it (unnecessarily) so you are looking for pipes or dots. What you want is

```
ans=re.search(r"\w+[\\.]*\w+", txt1)
```

Comment: email="bogusemail123@sillymail.com"

>>> x=re.search('\w+[.|\w]@(\w+[.])*(com$|in$)',email)

>>> x.group()
'bogusemail123@sillymail.com'

This one works with OR.....

Comment: That is because you have no backslash in the character class. `[.|\w]` will match a dot, pipe, or word character when you mean simply `[.\w]`. In your original post you had `[\|.]` and the backslash acted to escape the pipe, so it is the same as `[|.]`.

Comment: Oh.......I completely did'nt get that.......You are right...Thanks for bringing a serious mistake to my attention....Thank you very much...

Answer (score 1):

**"I intend to find a regex that will return me the special symbols."**

```
re.search(r"\w+([\\\.]*)\w+", txt1)
```

finds with `ans.group(1)` what you need:

```
ans = re.search(r"\w+([\\\.]*)\w+", txt1)
ans.group(1)

# '\\.\\..'
```

The `[]` designs a group of characters (without the `|` "or"), but you have to escape the backslash and dot with backslash `\. -> \\\.` to match it.

Comment: I was under the impression that the symbols mentioned in the Square [] need not be escaped with backlash...Thanks for the correction

Comment: Not an error as such, but a dot inside a character class doesn't need escaping.

Comment: Only a backslash needs escaping, and only then because `[\.]` would be seen as an unnecessarily escaped dot. A caret `^` needs escaping only if it is the first character of a character class, where it would otherwise be seen as negating the whole class.

Comment: Sidenote that `-` (not used here) does need escaping, but only if there is doubt as to its literality. You can use `[a-]` but not `[a-9]` if you mean `[a\-9]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find anything in there that isn't alphanumeric (including spaces) then use:

```
[^\w]+
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to find special symbols, `re.findall(r"[a-z]*([.\\] ?)[a-z]*", txt1)` will return your symbols as a list. You can always `join()` them as needed (example shown below):

```
>>> 
>>> txt1
'fdf\\.\\..dgg'
>>> ans = re.findall(r"[a-z]*([.\\] ?)[a-z]*", txt1)
>>> ans
['\\', '.', '\\', '.', '.']
>>> 
>>> "".join(ans)
'\\.\\..'
>>>
```